Can't assign a value to this object (Access VBA) Me. object
So I have the below code that runs fine in VBA application on a button click, however when I go to rerun it after changing values of certain fields.  The code stops on Me.PCN with the following error.

Is there a way to reassign these values dynamically?
Me.PCN = Me.txt_PCN.Value
Me.OldPN = Me.txt_oldPN.Value
Me.Qty_Change = Me.TXT_QTY.Value
Me.NewPart = Me.txt_PN_TO.Value

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryAdd_PNChange to tblTransaction", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryUpdatePNChange to tblWhse_Inventory", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryDelect Record from tblPNChange", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox "Transfer Completed"

Exit_error_save_click:
    Exit Sub
Error_Save_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_error_save_click

Tried to delete the objects but ran into another error with DoCmd.DeleteObject.

if Me.PCN is a bound control, you can't assign a value to it. You would have to change the value of the underlying data source.

@JohnWu, though I solved it with the below answer.  How would you go about changing the value of the data source?

Solved with adding the following to the top of the code, PN_Changed is the name of the form this particular program runs on
Forms("PN_Changed").RecordLocks = 0

